# Low contrast on many Meta design elements makes it hard to read

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, meta

I think this was brought up in one of the posts on the new design, but I'll throw it up here as an explicit problem.

I don't know if it's my monitor/gamma settings, but I still have trouble reading the name of the asker with the light salmon text on top of a white background.  If we're in love with light pink, can we at least set it against a dark (black?) background?

---

### [image: example of low contrast]

Comment: I totally agree and no, it's not your monitor. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made some contrast changes per your report. They'll be in the next prod build.