# Username is hard to read in comments posted by the OP on meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, meta

Apparently, when the contrast of some UI elements was increased on meta.scifi.SE per [this request](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1609/low-contrast-on-many-meta-design-elements-makes-it-hard-to-read), one case was missed: the username of the question owner is still shown as light pink on white in comments:

> [image: Screenshot before fix]

An easy fix would be to make the current CSS rule:

```
.owner a, .owner a:visited {
    color: #ca4040;
}
```

read instead as:

```
.owner a, .owner a:visited, a.owner, a.owner:visited {
    color: #ca4040;
}
```

With this simple change, the link color becomes a much more readable dark pink:

> [image: Screenshot after fix]

Comment: It wouldn't bother me to change it to a darker pink and I'm happy to go with the flow; truthfully, I can read both examples equally well. Just thought I'd throw that out there, but, again, it wouldn't bother me if it were changed.

Comment: I can't really see much difference and both are readable on my monitor.

Comment: I can read both, but the second one is definitely clearer. I'd be happy to go with it.

Comment: My vision is pretty good, but if it were a bit blurrier I'd have trouble reading the first one.  So I approve of the change for those who are vision-impaired.

Comment: I have to look closely to see the difference between the two. To me, they are both readable.

Comment: Is this a [tag:bug] or a [tag:feature-request]?

Comment: @SQB: I've tagged it as a bug, since a) it's [clearly](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5084/color-scheme-on-meta-is-not-good?lq=1#comment13749_5085) a usability issue for some users, b) it was [requested before](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1609/low-contrast-on-many-meta-design-elements-makes-it-hard-to-read), and the request was marked as [tag:status-completed], and c) looking at the CSS code, it seems pretty likely that the rule I quoted is *supposed* to apply to comments too, and the fact that it doesn't is just an oversight.

Comment: @DVK: you've been graphically mentioned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your feedback. I have modified the CSS as you requested and confirmed that it does appear to make the OP's display name much more visible in their comments. It will be live in the next meta build (> `rev 2014.10.16.1945`).